# JPA retrieve part of object

Tags: database, hibernate, rest, jpa

In sql you can easily select a few columns out of the whole table. How do you achieve such a thing in JPA ?
And that's not actually my main question. It's more of an design one.

Let's say i have a parent object with some information fields and a collection of child objects field with a one to many connection.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "code")
public class CodeList extends Code {

        /** The code list's values. */
        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "codeListId")
        private List<CodeValue> codeValues;


        /** The code list's display type. */
        @Column(length = 255, name = "DISPLAY_TYPE")
        private String displayType;
....
```

I am trying to implement a rest service using JPA (Hibernate) and jax-rs but what if i want my service to be able to retrieve just the information of the CodeList ( the displayType ) or just the collection of codeValues without any extra performance overhaul (nulling out the objects) or retrieval from the database of extra data that i dont need ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default @OneToMany relationship is LAZY .

simple value :

```
SELECT c.displayType FROM CodeList c WHERE c.id=:id
```

relationship

```
SELECT v FROM CodeList c LEFT JOIN c.codeValues v WHERE c.id=:id
```

Answer (score 1):

Use JPQL to determine which values you want to retrieve.

```
select e.displayType from CodeList e
```

OR

```
select e from CodeList d left join fetch d.codeValues e
```

Comment: i think that this won't work with the 'fetch' keyword. we use 'fetch' when we are attempting to retrieve the parent entity ( d in this case). can you confirme that ?

Comment: As onetoMany is lazy I used fetch to bring it the values. fetch obtain values for lazy attributes (collections or not).